# window.onload starts before indexed db statements

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, onload

Good afternoon all,

My issue is javascript related, I have made one function called checkflights, a series of statements to open an indexeddb database and one window.onload that triggers checkflights.

It seems that the window.onload triggers before the open database statements and therefor the checkflights function does not run properly as the db is considered null.

Any solution? code here below. Thank you in advance for your support.

```
    var db = null
    const request = indexedDB.open('MyDataBase', '1')

    //on upgrade needed
    request.onupgradeneeded = e => {
        var db = e.target.result
        /* note = {
            title: "note1",
            text: "this is a note"
        }*/
        const myFlights = db.createObjectStore("my_flight", {
            keyPath: "flightid"
        })
        
    }
    
    request.onsuccess = e => {
        var db = e.target.result 
    
    }

    request.onerror = e => {
        alert(`error: ${e.target.error} was found `)
    }    

window.onload = function () {
        checkFlights()

    }

function checkFlights() {
        const tx = db.transaction("my_flight", "readonly");
        // var objectStore = transaction.objectStore('my_flight');
        const mesVols=tx.objectStore("my_flight")

        var countRequest = mesVols.count();
        countRequest.onsuccess = function() {
            console.log(countRequest.result);
            if(countRequest.result>0 && window.navigator.onLine){
                sendFlights()
                notify("Flights sent to server")
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: window.onload just waits for the dom to render, and for any external scripts to load -  it doesn't take into account async scripts being completed

Comment: Thank you Kinglish, any lead on how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are redeclaring `db` from the outer scope, by using `var` again.
When using `var` in a local scope, you are not affecting the variable from the outer scope and actually creating a new local `db` variable.

```
 var db = null
    const request = indexedDB.open('MyDataBase', '1');
    //on upgrade needed
    request.onupgradeneeded = e => {
         db = e.target.result
        /* note = {
            title: "note1",
            text: "this is a note"
        }*/
        const myFlights = db.createObjectStore("my_flight", {
            keyPath: "flightid"
        })
        
    }
    
    request.onsuccess = e => {
         db = e.target.result 
    
    }

    request.onerror = e => {
        alert(`error: ${e.target.error} was found `)
    }    

window.onload = function () {
        checkFlights()

    }

function checkFlights() {
        const tx = db.transaction("my_flight", "readonly");
        // var objectStore = transaction.objectStore('my_flight');
        const mesVols=tx.objectStore("my_flight")

        var countRequest = mesVols.count();
        countRequest.onsuccess = function() {
            console.log(countRequest.result);
            if(countRequest.result>0 && window.navigator.onLine){
                sendFlights()
                notify("Flights sent to server")
                }
        }
    }
```

As suggested by @Kinglish in a comment above, you might need to wait for the request to be handled. IndexedDB does not return a promise but you could write an async/await wrapper yourself around the top part or consider using a library like https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb that will Promisify indexedDB.

Comment: @Mouss you can accept the solution using the checkmark under the vote counter

Comment: copy that, sorry I am new. Thanks